# Delaying pulse signal

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design

How can you add a tunable delay to a pulse?
My goal is to make as simples as possible, a circuit that I could control how much delay it can add to a pulse. The detailed photo about delayed pulses is shown as below. Is there a way to do it without a microcontroller? This question is not homework.I would appreciate if you could help me for this question.

[image]

Comment: you write code. This is really like a hello-world-example for using a microcontroller. Both the duration of the delay and the adjustability *strongly* suggest a microcontroller is the easiest, cheapest, most precise and lowest part count solution to this.

Comment: Can it be done without a micro-controller? Perhaps. But it seems that a micro-controller might be the easiest way. Another way would be to use an RC filter followed by a comparator. The times given (seconds) are too long to delay with practical delay lines. My suggestion would be that if possible, the source of signal 1 should be modified so that it can also produce signals 2 and 3. But maybe that is not an option for you.

Comment: Do you need a _transport delay_ or more like an _inertial delay_? In other words, do you need to reproduce an arbitrary input at the output, or do you only need a pulse of a certain width when triggered by an input pulse? The latter is not so hard with discretes.

Comment: Dear Marcus Müller, If I write code with using microcontroller, how can I apply this code in microcontroller. I'm beginner at embedded system or microcontroller system.

Comment: I would appreciate how I could hello-world example for using a microcontroller @Marcus Müller Thank you so much

Comment: What microcontroller family you have access to and can program? Also take a look at @TypeIA questions.

Comment: @too6hort I can't give you an intro to *all* of the thousands of microcontrollers out there. Anyways, STM32 nucleo boards are ~10 to 15€, and come with many examples.

Comment: @TypeIA I need a transport delay.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Could you share link or something about delaying pulse signal example with using STM32?

Comment: @too6hort "I need a transport delay" are you sure? your picture suggests a fixed 1s pulse duration.

Comment: Can you explain how you intend to specify the delay time? With a control voltage? A potentiometer? What's your source of "control"?

Comment: The control depends on delay time. The difference between two pulses should be 2 second. @SimonFitch

Comment: @too6hort I don't understand - all you've quoted so far are fixed, unchanging values. You say duration is 1s, that's given. You say period is 13s, nothing variable about that. The second pulse must come 2s after the first, and the third another 2s after that. These are all constants. What's changing? What are you actually trying to "tune"?

Comment: Nowadays, a MCU is the cheap and simple solution. Getting this up and running on some pre-made MCU evaluation board is a few hours of work. Coming up witch schematics and then hand-soldering some 74HC binary counter and oscillator takes longer than that, plus you might have to order & wait for the parts. But then I'm a software guy so I might be biased... :)

Answer (score 2):

Two cascaded 555 timers (or a 7556) both in monostable mode with a differentiator on each Trigger input. The differentiators create short negative going trigger pulses from the falling edges of longer pulses.

On falling edge of arriving pulse the first 555 outputs a pulse of adjustable length, adjustable with a pot. Falling edge of this pulse triggers the second 555 monostable which outputs a 1 second pulse.

I've used a switch and pull down resistor to generate the input pulse.

[image: Pulse delay circuit]

Comment: The answer by OP to @TypeIA question in comments suggests that OP wants to replicate the original pulse length, not to trigger another pulse of fixed length. Unless, of course, the OP is confused about the difference.

Comment: @Maple I understand your point. Of course my suggestion is only good for outputting a pulse of fixed length.

Comment: A 556 IC contains two 555 timers, might want to add that to your answer.

Comment: @James Thanks for your comment. Could you draw a block diagram of cascaded system? I would appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Since the period is constant and delay is a multiple of PW, a simple CMOS inverter 1Hz oscillator will do, with a 13bit Johnson counter to select the appropriate 1,4,7 outputs with 2x10bit chips and reset by the 14th bit. ~$3 in parts on a perf. Board with a 9V battery or 3 to 18V.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What is the PW?

Comment: @too6hort ... see your own drawing!

Comment: PW = 1 /1  Hz = 1s as the clock input.